# Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions

Tags: iis, applicationpoolidentity

I am trying to test my Web Service on an IIS instance on my local machine before I promote to a windows server 2008 environment.  I get this when I attempt to browse to the service.  I have created a custom application pool that this service will run under btw.  So I am guessing that that application ID does not have permissions to access that folder etc...  I get this little detail btw...

"This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs may contain more information about what caused this error."

I am thinking I need to give that application identity permissions, but I am unsure how to accomplish this.

Is there another way to get this done?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Not sure whether this is too late for you.

The **IIS** website is run by either **USERS** or **IIS_IUSRS**.

Try to do following:

- From Windows Explorer
- Right click on the folder pointed by the web
- Go to security tab
- Add **`computername\IIS_IUSRS`** or **`computername\USERS`** with **Read** permission.

Answer (score 15):

1.Open IIS 
2.On left side panel click on application pools
3.And go to its properties and change identity value from "ApplicationPoolIdentity" to "Local System".

I resolved the problem when i tried this.

Comment: Thanks alot... I waste lot of time adding IIS_IUSRS or config permissions etc.. But resolved issue by following your answer..

Comment: Indeed a great solution, I was also not happy with adding user and permissions over every damn folder

Comment: This also solved my problem rather than adding IUSR in my permission :)

Comment: That is a lot of permissions to grant to a web site account. You should not do this for a production system.

Comment: Local System is actually incredibly dangerous. It is such a highly privileged account. Far too high to be granting to any ApplicationPoolIdentity for a publicly visible site. (I'd excuse it, possibly, if you're doing it on an intranet site with some weird requirements) - I'd recommend you use Local Service instead.

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar issue on Windows 8.1. I fixed it by changing identity value from `ApplicationPoolIdentity` to `Local System`.

Answer (score 4):

Check your sites **Security -> Authentication** feature.  If **anonymousAuthentication** is **enabled**, click on the **Edit** link (in the Actions column) to see which identity is being used; if it is **IUSR**, make sure IUSR has FileSystem ACL privileges on the website's folder and files.  If it set to '**ApplicationPoolIdentity**' make sure group **IIS_IUSRS** has the same rights, because the 'ApplicationPoolIdentity' is dynamically added to the **IIS_IUSRS** group at runtime.

Comment: It depends on the IIS version. it can be `IUSR` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying the application's identity setting from "ApplicationPoolIdentity" to "LocalSystem" on IIS(7) solved my issue. when adding  permission to the IIS_IUSRS did not. I don't quite understand why though.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I just transferred my files under c:\inetpub\wwwroot and the error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was edit permissions for the virtual directory(application) in IIS 7.5 and add IUSR to the permissions.  That fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you chosen old version of .Net framework in application pool of IIS may sometimes cause this issue. So Try with higher .net framework version.